# asp.net self hosting coupling issue and multiple hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin, self-hosting

Self hosting a WEB.API Project is possible through OwinSelfHost with console application. All examples shows adding controllers and routing handling the the same console application, this leads to tight coupling web.api project with console application. I have three questions.

1. How to host web.api project like IIS. separate console project to host 
   separate web.api project.
2. In production, console application has to be a windows service, if web.api 
   project is created as a separate project independent from console 
   application, would it be an issue.
3. if it is possible to use console application with OwinSelfHost as a web 
   server, is it possible to host multiple web.api services in one console 
   application ?

Comment: You don't need console app to host in IIS.  If you can share your structure of project and what you want achieve better solution can be provided.

Comment: I want to host a web.api project using owin self hosting. owin self hosting needs a console application to run it's own web server. most examples shows adding web.api controllers and routing to the same console application and serving controllers on request. having controllers in the same console application generates tight coupling among them. I want to know a way to have them as separate two projects. hope this explains my view.

Comment: There is nothing that prevents you from defining the controllers in a separate assembly. In a worst case scenario you need an `AssembyResolver` so that the console app that hosts the api's can find the controllers, see https://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/ or https://perpetualprogrammers.wordpress.com/2016/05/15/api-discovery-with-owin-self-host/

Comment: Is it possible to have controllers in an independent ASP.NET web API project hosted using owin self hosting ? so the solution would contain two projects, one, web API project and console application that host the web API project using owin. I know controllers can be separated using a class library project. advantage of hosting a separate web API project is, separation of concern and later I can host the web API project in any web server as well.